# How do I breed a Pollen Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I received an in game announcement that a new Pollen Dragon is available for breeding. What is the best pair for breeding?  What is the breeding time (so I know if I was successful)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the Dragon Vale Wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Pollen_Dragon)

> The Pollen Dragon can be bred by selecting an air dragon to mate with a plant dragon at the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.

And the breeding time is 7 hours whereas the [Willow Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Willow_Dragon) is 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Plant and air works for the pollen dragon